# maven-jar-plugin repository layout combined with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins

So I am using the maven jar plugin to copy my projects dependencies to a lib folder in the target folder.

I set the classpathLayoutType to repository (repository) since some of the dependencies have the same name.

The manifest now states something like this: lib/some/group/id/artifact/version/artifact.jar

However the maven dependency plugin, which I use to copy the dependencies to the lib folder does not follow this layout. It just copies the dependencies to the base of the lib folder. How can I change this behavior to match that of the jar plugin?

Comment: First what would you like to achieve? Copying files to a lib folder? generating a executable jar ?

Comment: I'd like the layout of the lib folder generated by the dependency plugin to match the expected classpath locations stated in the manifest (generated by the maven jar plugin). This is what the manifest states: http://i.imgur.com/zPqJaRA.png But the libs aren't actually copied into that folder but the root of  the libs folder. And I can't have that happen since the dependencies have the same name (I can not change this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the maven dependency plugin, and goal `copy-dependencies` setting [useRepositoryLayout](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#useRepositoryLayout) to `true` should do the trick

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks!